# JavaScript - check if any radio button inputs = no

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML form which has a series of yes/no questions for the user to complete. I have an existing script to check if the user selects no for all the answers and shows a dialog box alert.

I now need to change this slightly so instead of checking if they selected 'No' for **every** input I now need to check if they have selected 'No' for **any** input.

Here's my current script that checks for all No answers:

```
var isAllNo = Object.values(inputs).every(function(q){
          return q === 'No'
      });

      if(isAllNo){
        if (confirm('You have selected "No" for your answers. Do you wish to continue?')) {
          console.log('Thing was saved to the database.');
        } else {
          console.log('Thing was not saved to the database.');
          ev.preventDefault();
        }          
      }
```

I haven't been able to find the syntax or how to change this to check for any No responses instead.

Comment: Replace `.every` by `.some` and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `.every` to `.some`.

```js
var isAllNo = Object.values(inputs).some(function(q){
          return q === 'No'
      });

      if(isAllNo){
        if (confirm('You have selected "No" for your answers. Do you wish to continue?')) {
          console.log('Thing was saved to the database.');
        } else {
          console.log('Thing was not saved to the database.');
          ev.preventDefault();
        }          
      }
```